# Как выполнить нажатие кнопки на сайте с помощью js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выполнить нажатие кнопки через 3 сек на сайте с помощью js кода.

```
<div class="dg_coupon_btn tmp-login">
<input type="submit" data-role="none" value="Кнопка" class="tg__btn tg__1 tg__2 tg__3 tg-4">
```

Comment: вам нужно именно на `input` нажимать?

Comment: Да, сколько бы не гуглил не могу найти

Comment: используйте `.click()`

Comment: не помогает это

Comment: а так помогает?

Comment: К сожалению но нет ( но большое спасибо за старание

Comment: а что показывает-то? как именно "не работает"?

Comment: Могли бы мы списаться может в вк ?

Comment: В Discord пойдёт?

Comment: Discord указан в моём профиле https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/548252/peter-kolosov

Comment: Что, Discord никак?

Comment: Я отправил заявку в друзья вам

Comment: Если есть возможность, может лучше вк ?

Comment: Нет, извините, вк нету(

Comment: а вы `id` к `<input type="submit">` добавили?

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так:

HTML:

```html
<div class="dg_coupon_btn tmp-login">
<input type="submit" data-role="none" value="Кнопка" class="tg__btn tg__1 tg__2 tg__3 tg-4" id="js_submit_btn">
```

(скопируйте HTML туда, куда надо)

JavaScript:

```js
const submitBtn = document.querySelector("#js_submit_btn");

setTimeout(() => {
    submitBtn.click();
}, 3000); // 3000 - это время задержки в миллисекундах, например для 1 секунды будет 1000 миллисекунд
```

Можно обернуть JavaScript код выше в функцию, и он будет вызываться только тогда, когда вы его вызовете.

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: нужно не setTimeout, а DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в вопросе явно написано, что через 3 секунды

Comment: а не при загрузке страницы

Comment: Окей. Но замечу, что проблемы у кода могут быть. Например контент ещё не загружен и в submitBtn  будет просто null. Так что важно в правильное место это написать.... Также, возможно, автор считает что 3 сек. достаточно для загрузки контента и именно DOMContentLoaded  пытается сэмулировать.... но интернет у всех разный... Просто на всяк случай пишу)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Окей, я не против))